# How to generate random pixels around the screen?

Tags: c++

I'm setting my new code, and i have an problem with code.
The box is always located at the top left in the screen.

let me explain the code.
r is need to generate random locations around the screen.
r + 256 is specify the animated pixels size ( 256 ) is creating a box.
RGB is just a the colors of the box.

How do i do that the box will generated in random location around the screen ?

I tried to play with the code, change the variables , etc.

```
int main() 
{

    int r = rand() % 400;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());

    while (true)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        srand(GetTickCount64());
        for (int x = r; x < r + 256; x++)
        for (int y = r; y < r + 256; y++)
        SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(127, x % 256, y % 256));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: What made you think calling `srand` would change `r`? I think you have some serious misconception about how programs work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you for your answer, i will not doing this again.

Comment: I think I understood. If you write `r = rand() % 400` that doesn't mean that later on all occurences of `r` will be replaced by `rand() % 400`. It means that the result of `rand() % 400` is put into `r`, that's all. You need to read again cour lecture notes or start reading your beginner's progammer book.

Comment: @Jabberwocky But it working, it just printing only pixels in diagonal line. Can you help with this ?

Comment: Please ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int r = rand() % 400;` is only evaluated once, with the same starting point ("seed") for the random number generator every time you start the program.
Thus, `r` always has the same value.

Calling `srand` does not update `r`; it sets the seed for subsequent uses of `rand`.

You need to

- generate a new random number every time you want a different number,
- only seed the random number generator once, and *before* using `rand`.

So,

```
int main() 
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    HDC hdc = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());

    while (true)
    {
        int r = rand() % 400;
        for (int x = r; x < r + 256; x++)
            for (int y = r; y < r + 256; y++)
                SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(127, x % 256, y % 256));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edited - Its making pixels only in diagonal line.

Comment: @CodingUniversity Could that be because you only have one random number which you're using for both coordinates?